# unable to load different webView content in each tab with actionBarActivity

Tags: java, android, webview, tabs

I started a project with the template named "tabbed activity" with three tabs and I added a fourth one, and I would like to load a different url in each tab with webView's. I'm new in android studio and I suppose I have to do that with `webView`, but looking at google, tutorials, and of course at stackoverflow, I've seen people doing that with `tabActivity` instead of `ActionBarActivity`, and despite I have the last android studio version, it looks like the template from google is using deprecated classes which I find it truly bizarre... I'm really newbie with android studio but I'm trying to do it the way the template does, with the deprecated classes. It would be great if somebody could throw some light on those aspect I've mentioned above. And my main question is why when I run the app, it loads every time the same webView content or how to set a webView content for each tab. It always load the last tab url in all the tabs. 
This is what I'm doing in my mainActivity.java:

```
    package com.example.alfredo.guiaswebtabapp;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;
    private WebView myWebView;
    private WebView myWebView2;
    private WebView myWebView3;
    private WebView myWebView4;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
        // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
        // a reference to the Tab.
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });


        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
            // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
            // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
            // this tab is selected.

            switch (i) {
                case 0: {
                    // web view
                    this.myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
                    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
                    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    myWebView.loadUrl("http://example.com/1");
                }
                case 1: {
                    this.myWebView2 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
                    myWebView2.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                    WebSettings webSettings2 = myWebView2.getSettings();
                    webSettings2.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    myWebView2.loadUrl("http://example.com/2");
                }
                case 2:
                    this.myWebView3 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
                    myWebView3.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                    WebSettings webSettings3 = myWebView3.getSettings();
                    webSettings3.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    myWebView3.loadUrl("http://example.com/3");
                case 3:
                    this.myWebView4 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
                    myWebView4.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                    WebSettings webSettings4 = myWebView4.getSettings();
                    webSettings4.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    myWebView4.loadUrl("http://example.com/4");
            }

            actionBar.addTab(
                    actionBar.newTab()
                            .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                            .setTabListener(this)

            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've finally did some improvements to my code and basically I'm loading the four webView's in four different webView's after the `onCreate()` method, and set the attributes to hidden except the first one, and when I switch to another tab I set the attribute hidden to visible.
Hope this code can help someone and sorry for this newbie post, cheers!

```
    private WebView myWebView;
    private WebView myWebView2;
    private WebView myWebView3;
    private WebView myWebView4;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

this.myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://example.com/1");


        this.myWebView2 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview2);
        myWebView2.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        WebSettings webSettings2 = myWebView2.getSettings();
        webSettings2.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView2.loadUrl("http://example.com/2");
        myWebView2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        this.myWebView3 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview3);
        myWebView3.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        WebSettings webSettings3 = myWebView3.getSettings();
        webSettings3.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView3.loadUrl("http://example.com/3");
        myWebView3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        this.myWebView4 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview4);
        myWebView4.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        WebSettings webSettings4 = myWebView4.getSettings();
        webSettings4.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView4.loadUrl("http://example.com/4");
        myWebView4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);



mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                switch (position) {
                    case 0: {
                        // web view
                        myWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        myWebView2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        myWebView3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        myWebView4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        break;
                        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                    }
                    case 1: {

                        myWebView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        myWebView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        myWebView3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        myWebView4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        break;
                    }
                    case 2: {

                        myWebView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        myWebView2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        myWebView3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        myWebView4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        break;
                    }
                    case 3: {
                        myWebView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        myWebView2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        myWebView3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        myWebView4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```